# Add a background colour with opacity to an img tag

Tags: html, css, image, overlay

I am restricted to adding an any additional HTML markup to create an overlay div to do this.

However with the markup I have I need to put a dark overlay with opacity over the top of the image.

```
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

Markup is:

```
<div class="fusion-image-wrapper">
     <a href"#">
        <img src="image-path" >
    </a>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: your title is confusing ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use ::after so you don't have to add another element

```
.fusion-image-wrapper a {
   position: relative;
   display: block;
}

.fusion-image-wrapper a::after {
   content: "";
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: pay attention, you will cover the link and thus you can not more click it

Comment: you're right, I updated my answer to not cover it :)

Comment: i would go with inline-block for `a` which is more close to inline or you will make it full width in this case

Comment: also better create snippet so we can see the result and avoid any confusion ;)

Comment: well, yeah, he can style it however he wants, I just gave the idea of using ::after

Comment: Clearly you posted too fast and forgot to add position absolute.

Comment: Theres loads of pre generated code so its hard for me to create a snippet. The position absolute done it!!! :-)

Comment: @Stickers was going to point this out too :)

Comment: haha yeah, but again, the idea was to let him know he can use ::after, styling can be fixed :) but I updated it, thanks both ;)

Comment: yes but better take your time to write the answer to avoid getting downvotes because you simply missed a small thing ;)

Answer (score 1):

So you need a transparent image over a black background :)

```css
.darkenImage{
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;          /* :) */
}

.darkenImage img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  opacity: 0.5;              /* :) */
}
```

```html
<a class="darkenImage" href="#">
   <img src="https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/4698_27827105189_d6ce3f3401_n_300_200_nofilter.jpg" >
</a>
```

And if you use a mix of .jpg and **.png** images you can add `background: #fff;` to the `img` styles.

Comment: intresting, but this will make EXACTLY the same visual output as using the overlay on the top ?

Comment: yep, EXACTLY THE SAME :) since the image is at `0.5` opacity over a black background :) Color math stays the same

Comment: yes but i guess if we consider another opacity we should do the opposite ... if initialy we want 0.2, we should do 0.8 on the image, right ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes :) you got that perfectly right :)

Comment: so i guess this deserve some explanation to make the answer more relevant as here we have a particular case ;)